# Change default p:dataTable pagination size

Tags: primefaces

Primefaces datatable with pagination normally shows only 10 pages to navigate if it has more records.How to change this default value for 15 pages to view at once.
(see image)

[Primefaces pagination pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ1lE.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, big fat downvote. There is a very old abbreviation on the internet. I never used it, but with this question it is impossible not use it. Please… RTFM, they write this for a reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation) a dataTable can have a `pageLinks` attribute. The default is 10.

Give it a try with `pageLinks="15"`.

Comment: Don't know 100% why but a fat upvote from me. Just for keeping the calmness to answer it